# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - May 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. Most Edited Questions Award.
15. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

## Monthly Leader Board.

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-05-01)

### [image]

## Most Active Contributors Award.

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                    1329
2   Danny '365CSI' Engelman     1123
3   InnovaITve Solutions        1020
4   Venkat Konjeti              887
5   Gautam Sheth                713
```

---

## Most Active Editors Award.

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   InnovaITve Solutions       370
2   M.Qassas                   268
3   Suresh Bolineni            141
4   TARUN                      111
5   Robert Lindgren            83
```

---

## Most Active Voters Award.

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Guero                       954
2   R_Viper                     681
3   Danny '365CSI' Engelman     497
4   Aashirya                    403
5   M.Qassas                    284
```

---

## Most Close Votes Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Robert Lindgren              16
2   M.Qassas                     15
3   Gautam Sheth                 12
4   Waqas Sarwar MVP             9
5   Asad Refai                   8
```

---

## Most First Post Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                    61
2   hoffie4                     51
3   Gaurravs                    48
4   Robert Lindgren             31
5   moe                         21
```

---

## Most Late Answer Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   hoffie4                      22
2   M.Qassas                     21
3   Gaurravs                     15
4   P S                          10
5   moe                          10
```

---

## Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     49
2   P S                          28
3   M.Qassas                     22
4   Mike                         20
5   Asad Refai                   17
```

---

## Most Reopen Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Dikesh Gandhi                8
2   M.Qassas                     7
3   Robert Lindgren              7
4   wjervis                      4
5   Asad Refai                   4
```

---

## Most Suggested Edit Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     160
2   Gaurravs                     153
3   Gautam Sheth                 129
4   P S                          95
5   Robert Lindgren              86
```

---

## Highest Votes Questions Award.

1. [New List Experience allow bypass security bits (Item-level Permissions)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217325/new-list-experience-allow-bypass-security-bits-item-level-permissions)

   - Quest Owner: ppatalong.
   - Votes: 9.
2. [When to use RBS and when not to](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216930/when-to-use-rbs-and-when-not-to)

   - Quest Owner: Omegacron.
   - Votes: 9.
3. [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin)

   - Quest Owner: Vishnu S.
   - Votes: 8.

---

## Highest Votes Answers Award.

1. [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin)

   - Answer Owner: Danny '365CSI' Engelman.
   - Votes: 12.
2. [Column Validation Settings for a mandatory choice](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216268/column-validation-settings-for-a-mandatory-choice/216272#216272)

   - Answer Owner: S Merchant.
   - Votes: 8.
3. [How to provide contribute without edit permissions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217568/how-to-provide-contribute-without-edit-permissions/217570#217570)

   - Answer Owner: M.Qassas.
   - Votes: 7.

---

## Most Viewed Questions Award.

1. [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin)

   - Views: 1004.
2. [How to provide contribute without edit permissions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217568/how-to-provide-contribute-without-edit-permissions)

   - Views: 647.
3. [How do I create Upload only permission in SharePoint Online ?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216091/how-do-i-create-upload-only-permission-in-sharepoint-online)

   - Views: 225.

---

## Most Edited Questions Award.

1. [Can't login to VM SharePoint 2016 from the network](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216707/cant-login-to-vm-sharepoint-2016-from-the-network)

   - Edits: 10.
2. [Validating product # against another list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216377/validating-product-against-another-list)

   - Edits: 8.

---

## 1st Top Contributors list.

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [InnovaITve Solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/66704/innovaitve-solutions) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Guero](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34941/guero) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [Robert Lindgren](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15141/robert-lindgren) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [hoffie4](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52982/hoffie4)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Dikesh Gandhi](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/29853/dikesh-gandhi) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [ppatalong](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/11797/ppatalong) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-365csi-engelman) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: The monthly interval for summaries looks good to me. It'll call for a bit of manual work, but I'd love to see at least on the yearly summary e.g. top appearances on the monthly contributor list. So at maximum a user might have had 12 appearances on the top contributor list, etc.

Comment: Thank you @moe for your precious feedback, it's a great Idea. We planned in Quarterly / Yearly report to highlight "How many times have you ever had the top contributor award? Is that what you want to add to the report؟ Please confirm with me :)

Comment: That's more or less just what I was after. That would be great!

Comment: Hearty congratulations to all winners!

Comment: Good job, M.Qassas on the monthly report.

Comment: Thank you @Aashirya :)

Comment: Thank you, @ArsalanAdamKhatri appreciate your valuable feedback :)

Comment: Remove most commented, comments aren't for discussion, and indicate a poorly written question or answer. It isn't something to be celebrated.

Comment: Good hint, the comment section has been deleted and All the coming report will not include it.