# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - June 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. Most Edited Questions Award.
15. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

## Monthly Leader Board.

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-06-02)

[image: ss]

---

## Most Active Contributors Award.

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                    2153
2   Venkat Konjeti              1869
3   moe                         1556
4   Waqas Sarwar MVP            1055
5   Gautam Sheth                1035
```

---

## Most Active Editors Award.

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   251
2   moe                        84
3   Robert Lindgren            64
4   Mike                       45
5   SynozeN IT Solutions       39
```

---

## Most Active Voters Award.

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aashirya                   361
2   Walt                       315
3   M.Qassas                   285
4   Habib                      270
5   Danny '365CSI' Engelman    233
```

---

## Most Close Votes Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     29
2   Gautam Sheth                 20
3   Aakash Morya                 16
4   Robert Lindgren              14
5   Waqas Sarwar MVP             11
```

---

## Most First Post Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   hoffie4                      65
2   moe                          63
3   M.Qassas                     35
4   Gaurravs                     30
5   Gautam Sheth                 30
```

---

## Most Late Answer Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   hoffie4                      18
2   Aakash Morya                 13
3   M.Qassas                     13
4   moe                          11
5   Gaurravs                     9
```

---

## Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   P S                          45
2   Gaurravs                     42
3   Aakash Morya                 37
4   moe                          34
5   Gautam Sheth                 28
```

---

## Most Reopen Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     7
2   Gautam Sheth                 4
3   Robert Lindgren              3
```

---

## Most Suggested Edit Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     54
2   Gautam Sheth                 35
3   moe                          31
4   Karthik Jaganathan           30
5   Robert Lindgren              23
```

---

## Highest Votes Questions Award.

1. [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

   - Quest Owner: CA.
   - Votes: 29.
2. [Is it possible to load the parameters of a single object using LoadQuery()](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218149/is-it-possible-to-load-the-parameters-of-a-single-object-using-loadquery)

   - Quest Owner: Mr_TC.
   - Votes: 9.
3. [Can I bulk upgrade deployed SPFx web parts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218054/can-i-bulk-upgrade-deployed-spfx-web-parts)

   - Quest Owner: Jason Lee.
   - Votes: 9.

---

## Highest Votes Answers Award.

1. [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

   - Answer Owner: Danny '365CSI' Engelman.
   - Votes: 16.
2. [SharePoint Dev and Prod running on same Farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218439/sharepoint-dev-and-prod-running-on-same-farm/218440#218440)

   - Answer Owner: Christoffer.
   - Votes: 9.
3. [How to disable new doc menu OWA2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218936/how-to-disable-new-doc-menu-owa2013/218942#218942)

   - Answer Owner: DvG.
   - Votes: 8.

---

## Most Viewed Questions Award.

1. [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

   - Views: 4012.
2. [Free Office 365 subscription](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218318/free-office-365-subscription)

   - Views: 1363.
3. [How to show pop up windows once per session or per day?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218561/how-to-show-pop-up-windows-once-per-session-or-per-day)

   - Views: 786.

---

## Most Edited Questions Award.

1. [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

   - Edits: 10.
2. [How to create Star Rating column in list programmatically using CSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218032/how-to-create-star-rating-column-in-list-programmatically-using-csom)

   - Edits: 8.
3. [SharePoint 2013: April-2017 CU Patch Update Mismatch](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217182/sharepoint-2013-april-2017-cu-patch-update-mismatch)

   - Edits: 7.

---

## 1st Top Contributors list.

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Aashirya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/62708/aashirya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [hoffie4](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52982/hoffie4) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [hoffie4](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52982/hoffie4) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [P S](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/41198/p-s)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [CA](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/67867/ca) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-365csi-engelman) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: Great job fellow contributors. Glad to see my name appearing on the lists as well. This has its positive sides on giving each of us the small extra thanks besides the statistics, so keep the work going on!

Comment: Great Job @moe your name has been listed **6th** times in **June 2017** .We are fully appreciated your valuable effort, Please Keep it up :)

Comment: Check also **Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - May 2017**: https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-may-2017

Comment: After a very long time I saw my name in **Monthly Leader Board** again.. Thanks @M.Qassas for your valuable reports.. It keeps encouraging us...

Comment: Great Job @AakashMorya ! You deserve to be classified within the **Top 10 Leader Board** Please keep up your wonderful contributions, Thank you for your valuable feedback :)

Comment: Hearty congratulations to all winners! happy to see my name "Most active voters Award" . Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Great Job @Aashirya Thank you for your valuable contributions.